# Mysql: Couldn't create a table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm a new in databases and I have some problem with creating table

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE FILMS (
-> film_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> film_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
-> film_mark FLOAT NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY_KEY (film_id)
-> );
```

Am getting below error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( film_id ))' at line 5
```

Version of mysql

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: try replacing PRIMARY_KEY  with PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @i'myourhuckleberry I have seen a lot of docs with mysql and there are `PRIMARY_KEY`. Can you share update documentation?

Comment: There is nothing to stop a coder creating a key called primary_key but it's not the same as a Primary Key directive.

Answer (score 4):

Change `PRIMARY_KEY` to `PRIMARY KEY` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50),
  reg_date TIMESTAMP
  )
```

this is an example.
w3schools is a good place to learn mysql.